# ctags unable to find variables that contain hyphen

Tags: vim, makefile, gnu-make, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I'm a big user of Vim's ctags ctrl-] shortcut. I recently made a tag file in which the primary language is Make. When I try to ctrl-] with my cursor over a variable with a hyphen (ex. dl-routines), I get an error. If my cursor is over 'dl' within the 'dl-routines' variable I get the error

```
tag not found: dl
```

If my cursor is over 'routines' within the 'dl-routines' variable I get the error

```
tag not found: routines
```

I'm aware of Vim's

```
:ta tagname
```

However I'd like to use ctrl-] as it gives me less room for error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case it's probably worth altering `'iskeyword'` option to include dash. It may have many other effects, but they all should be quite useful. The only trick is to make these changes locally:

```
autocmd FileType make setlocal iskeyword+=45
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting `'iskeyword'` option locally is probably the simplest solution. As an addendum to @Matt's answer, if you want to keep your option clean and add `45` *only* when you press `<C-]>`, you could use this trick function.

```
function! CWordWithKey(key) abort
    let s:saved_iskeyword = &iskeyword
    let s:saved_updatetime = &updatetime
    if &updatetime > 200 | let &updatetime = 200 | endif
    augroup CWordWithKeyAuGroup
        autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI <buffer>
                    \ let &updatetime = s:saved_updatetime |
                    \ let &iskeyword = s:saved_iskeyword |
                    \ autocmd! CWordWithKeyAuGroup
    augroup END
    execute 'set iskeyword+='.a:key
    return expand('<cword>')
endfunction
```

which adds the parameter `key` to iskeyword and sets a self-destructing autocmd to restore your older `iskeyword` after 200 ms.

Than remap `<C-]>` in `ftplugin/make.vim` or with `autocmd FileType make ...` as the previous answer.

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <C-]> :execute 'tag '.CWordWithKey(45)<CR>
```